# Ошибка при вводе русских символов

Tags: c#, asp.net

Есть текстовое поле и кнопка, при нажатии на кнопку содержимое поля записывается в текстовый файл. У другого пользователя возникла ошибка: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня не выходит повторить ошибку, и потому я понятия не имею как ее исправить.

Содержимое файла Defoult.aspx:

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="app.Default" %>
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
  <html>

  <head runat="server">
    <title>Default</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <asp:Button id="button1" runat="server" Text="Click me!" OnClick="button1_Click" />
      <asp:TextBox id="TextArea1" TextMode="multiline" Columns="50" Rows="5" runat="server" />
    </form>
  </body>

  </html>
```

Содержимое файла Defoult.aspx.cs:

```
namespace app {
  using System;
  using System.Web;
  using System.Web.UI;

  public partial class Default: System.Web.UI.Page {

    public void button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
      System.IO.File.AppendAllText("1.txt", TextArea1.Text, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
    }
  }
}
```

Содержимое файла web.config:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!--
Web.config file for app.

The settings that can be used in this file are documented at 
http://www.mono-project.com/Config_system.web and 
http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5ysx397.aspx
-->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation defaultLanguage="C#" debug="true">
      <assemblies>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly">
    </customErrors>
    <authentication mode="None">
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
    <httpHandlers>
    </httpHandlers>
    <trace enabled="false" localOnly="true" pageOutput="false" requestLimit="10" traceMode="SortByTime" />
    <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="20" />
    <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" />
    <pages>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, откуда берется ошибка

Comment: у другого пользователя - это у кого?

Comment: @titov_andrei  Ну я пересылала проект другому человеку. Может быть ошибка связана с файлом web.config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это ошибка валидатора запроса, который срабатывает, если на сервер в текстовом поле приходит что-то подозрительное. Например, кусок HTML, или кусок скрипта.

Чинится отключением, как и сказано в сообщении об ошибке - добавлением атрибута `validateRequest="false"` в тег  Page, или в соответствующем месте в web.config.